# Transcribe to use only stream()

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

how to transcribe this to use only stream ()?

List deposits = new ArrayList<>();

```
    Deposit deposit = new Deposit("deposito 1");
    Deposit deposit2 = new Deposit("deposito 2");
    Deposit deposit3 = new Deposit("deposito 3");

    deposits.add(deposit);
    deposits.add(deposit2);
    deposits.add(deposit3);

    List<String> status = Arrays.asList("DepositStatus.CANCELED", "DepositStatus.ERROR", "DepositStatus.DONE");
        Arrays.stream(st).distinct().forEach(s -> {
        for(int i = 0; i < deposits.size(); i++){
            deposits.get(i).setStatus(st[i]);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(deposits);
```

I need to set the status attribute of each deposit following the status index, to print something like this:

```
Deposit {name = 'deposit 1', status = 'DepositStatus.CANCELED'},
Deposit {name = 'deposit 2', status = 'DepositStatus.ERROR'},
Deposit {name = 'deposit 3', status = 'DepositStatus.DONE'}]
```

Deposit class

```
public class Deposit {

    private String nome;
    private String status;
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I edited more clearly

Answer (score 0):

- The `distinct()` seems redundant in this case.
- In the `forEach` you set to every element the given status at index `i`.
- `Mapping` seems more functional in this use-case than setting fields in a `forEach`.

Assuming the two lists are the same size, we can join them like this:

```
List<Deposit> depositsWithStatuses = IntStream.range(0, deposits.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> new Deposit(deposits.get(i).getName(), status.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(depositsWithStatuses);
```

Output:

```
[
 Deposit(name=deposit 1, status=DepositStatus.CANCELED),
 Deposit(name=deposit 2, status=DepositStatus.ERROR),
 Deposit(name=deposit 3, status=DepositStatus.DONE)
]
```

Note: If the lists are not the same size or you applied `distinct()` to a list
, you can do `IntStream.range(0, Math.min(deposits.size(),status.size()))...`

Answer (score 0):

A stream solution would not be appropriate here.  You can just use a status iterator and the original list as follows:

```
Iterator<String> it = status.iterator();
deposits.forEach(dep -> dep.setStatus(it.next()));

deposits.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Deposit {name = 'deposito 1', status = 'DepositStatus.CANCELED'}
Deposit {name = 'deposito 2', status = 'DepositStatus.ERROR'}
Deposit {name = 'deposito 3', status = 'DepositStatus.DONE'}
```

For lack of more information the above presumes that the order of deposits and status values match up.

I would imagine there is more that you haven't explained.  Otherwise, why not just have a `Deposit` class constructor that takes the `name and status` when the instances are created.

Here is the class with `toString` that provides the desired output.

```
class Deposit {
    private String name;
    private String status;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Deposit(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Deposit {name = '"+name+"', status = '"+status+"'}";
    }
    
}
```